# Windows Docker Push Stopped Working

Tags: docker, windows-10

Setup:
Insecure private registry in Kubernetes with kubectl port-forward to localhost.

Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

> curl http://127.0.0.1:8020/v2/_catalog
>
> ## works!
>
> docker push localhost:8020/hello-world
>
> ## failed!

Error Message:
The push refers to a repository [localhost:8020/hello-world]
Get http://localhost:8020/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8020: getsockopt: connection refused

Same push from Linux works.  And this used to work on Windows until IT pushed some new FW policies on Windows.  They since tried to remove the FW policies to trouble-shoot yet the problem persisted.

Any idea what else might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are network limitations built into Windows that you may be running into. Check out the [Docker for Windows documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#limitations-of-windows-containers-for-localhost-and-published-ports) for more information. "Limitations of Windows containers for localhost and published ports
Docker for Windows provides the option to switch Windows and Linux containers. If you are using Windows containers, keep in mind that there are some limitations with regard to networking due to the current implementation of Windows NAT (WinNAT). These limitations may potentially resolve as the Windows containers project evolves.

One thing you may encounter rather immediately is that published ports on Windows containers do not do loopback to the local host. Instead, container endpoints are only reachable from the host using the container’s IP and port."

Comment: Thanks Mano.  Just to be clear, we are dealing with straightly Linux containers (we are running docker in Windows only because historically we have been a Windows shop).  And the issue is not about networking to a running container, but simply docker push of *images* failing.